# Can't see FAT32 and NTFS external partitions on OS X El Capitan when SIP is enabled

Tags: hard-drive, macos, partition, ntfs

I've installed Homebrew, FUSE for OS X and NTFS-3G. It helped to see external partitions (FAT32 and NTFS) when SIP is disabled (OS X El Capitan).  But when SIP is enabled, I can't see NTFS and FAT32 external partitions in Finder and Disk Utility. When I run command `diskutil list` in a Terminal, it shows all partitions, including NTFS and FAT32.

What should I do now to read/write with SIP enabled?

Output from diskutil list:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            499.3 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +499.0 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 DD75E058-1FC0-4B05-B0F2-FB02A06EC189
                                 Unencrypted
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                80.9 GB    disk2s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS osxboot                 53.2 GB    disk2s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data NF                      365.6 GB   disk2s4
```

After command 'diskutil info /Volumes/NF'
Result was 'Could not find disk: /Volumes/NF'

Comment: Since you're using NTFS I'll assume you have a Windows system that you can attach the external drives to and run `chkdsk /f <drive letter>:` on from an Administrator Command Prompt, e.g., `chkdsk /f e:`  and then try mounting again under OS X.  This will ensure there are no issue with the filesystem, which under some circumstances may cause them not to mount properly.

Comment: thanks, for advice - I did what you've suggested, but nothing has changed.  Both partitions has normally functioning file systems. Anyway, now I'll know how to fix file system on Win :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason that FUSE will not run with SIP enabled, is that (amongst other things) SIP blocks changes to the `/sbin` filesystem location by default and this is where the "mount_XXXX" executable lives.

Instead of turning SIP off completely you can disable just the part that protects the filesystem support by running the following command in a recovery console.

> csrutil enable --without fs

This is the recommended way to get the NTFS module working in FUSE by the people who maintain [OSXFUSE](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/NTFS-3G).

Note that the command will give you the following warning but it will work for now.

> csrutil: requesting an unsupported configuration. This is likely to break in the future and leave your machine in an unknown state.

Comment: I did as you recommended, and I've got this: System Integrity Protection status: enabled (Custom Configuration).

Configuration:
 Apple Internal: disabled
 Kext Signing: enabled
 Filesystem Protections: disabled
 Debugging Restrictions: enabled
 DTrace Restrictions: enabled
 NVRAM Protections: enabled

This is an unsupported configuration, likely to break in the future and leave your machine in an unknown state.' But still I can't see neither ntfs nor fat32 partition.

Comment: So they still appear okay under `diskutil list` but don't appear in Disk Utility? Could you add the output of the `diskutil list` command to your question?

Comment: I've added diskutil list to my question.

Comment: @ade What happens if you just type `open /Volumes/NF` or `open /Volumes/BOOTCAMP` in a Terminal window?

Comment: When I write those commands, I'm getting the answers: 'the file  /Volumes/NF does not exist' and 'the file  /Volumes/BOOTCAMP does not exist' respectively.

Comment: Could you run `distutil info /Volumes/NF` and paste the output into your question?

Comment: I've added distutil info /Volumes/NF output to my question